# jQuery: drop item on multiple overlapping targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

JSFiddle (demo): http://jsfiddle.net/mr_goodcat/9a7qv/5/

I have a situation, where an item drops on multiple overlapping targets. The problem is that only one drop handler is called when it happens. If the code is as following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#droppable1").droppable();
  $("#droppable2").droppable();
  $("#droppable3").droppable();

  $("#draggable").draggable();

  $("#droppable1").bind("drop", drop);
  $("#droppable2").bind("drop", drop);
  $("#droppable3").bind("drop", drop);
});

function drop(e, ui) {
  $("#result").prepend("<p>" + ui.draggable.attr("id") + " ON " + $(this).attr("id") + "</p>");
}
```

I will only see "draggable ON droppable1" appended to the result div. (What's intresting: #droppable3 is on the top).

**Question:** How (if possible at all) to make drop event to be called on every droppable?

Answer (score 1):

I personally find the jQuery drag and drop functionalities to be incomplete.  Check out this jQuery extension that allows you to do exactly what you want.  There is a demo on this link that does exactly what you want.

http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop

Answer (score 0):

"drop" is not a true javascript event. What jQuery does is to loop all droppable elements in the order they were defined and return the first one that matches the coordonates of the dropped element. Perhaps you could define your own function for that. What your drop function should do is check drop zones in the order of the stack order. I don't know how to check an element's stack order but you can predict it provided the browser you're using respects the css2 specs.

also, if all of the drop zones are relatively positioned it's enough to check the z-index of each element and order in which they were declared. If instead you use negative margins or other methods for stacking elements on a page you have to read the css2 stacking specs.
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html

You could however initialize the droppable zones in the order of their corresponding stack order if you know them in advance and if they do not change. In your example that would be:

```
$("#droppable3").droppable();
$("#droppable2").droppable();
$("#droppable1").droppable();
```